# Get names of associates that shares the same manager in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to get the names (or preferably email addresses) of people that shares the same manager as me in Outlook (so basically my teammates) and my manager's email as well. I know how to get my manager's mail, but I'm struggling with the first part. 
Is there a possibility to achieve that? In Outlook I can go into Contact Card - Organization - Shares Same Manager, so I guess it should be possible to do this from VBA.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim mail As Object
Set mail = Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry

Dim mgrMail As String
mgrMail = mail.GetExchangeUser.Manager 'Works fine

Dim teamMails() As String
teamMails = ???? 'Is there a possibilty to get it somehow?
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ExchangeUser.GetDirectReports` (`mail.GetExchangeUser.Manager.GetDirectReports` in your case).

Comment: Works fine! Thanks.